# Flutter+Firebase - Can I use Windows to develop for iOS and Android after setting up everything in Xcode?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, macos

I set up everything with Xcode through a friend's Mac, can I now continue to develop with VScode through Windows?

Comment: Short n simple answer, No you can't.  Only android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.